# Is there a name for forecasting present and past quantities based on present data?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'm not talking about backtesting, where you simulate forecast results based on past data only.

The situation I'm talking about is when a metric about the present or past hasn't been completely observed yet (such as economic variables) so it has a certain degree of uncertainty. However, it converges to some value eventually. My specific case is credit card fraud (you only know if a transaction is fraudulent by waiting for customer chargebacks that have a time delay).

What I want is to forecast this converged value about something that already happened. Is there a name for this? Or do I just frame it as a simple forecast? I was taking a look at "hindcasting" but it seems to be a synonymous with (or part of) backtesting.

Comment: Similar to "now-casting"?

Comment: Yes! "Pastcasting" has only 279 Google results though :(, maybe "nowcasting" covers it as well?

Comment: For a school project I used Google Trends Correlate for some "now-casting", but then in early 2017 Google stopped updating the data ... so it quickly became useless for now-casting. <rant>Since 2017 I tried contacting Google many, many times via email, twitter, etc., to ask about updating their correlate data.  Google ***NEVER RESPONDED***!</rant> And now Google has completely canceled this service claiming "low usage".  I suspect Google Correlate became a victim of the rumored "You can't get ahead at Google supporting current projects.  You must launch something new!" syndrome.

Comment: @rickhg12hs more likely it has to do with the fact that the main person behind the nowcasting model (BSTS) was fired from Google.

Comment: @SkanderH.-ReinstateMonica I can appreciate the role champions play pushing innovation, but it's a serious problem if an organization can't keep up enough to even support a working system.  It should be about the service, not the personalities.  Watch, Google Correlate will reappear as a paid service somewhere.